# Is any corporate sponsorship allowable on this site?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, proposal

PROPOSAL:

1. Ask Logos Bible Software to sponsor regular contests in order to drum up support
2. See if Logos Bible Software would like to incorporate our questions and answers into their passage guide

Benefits:

1. Prizes for us (Credit with which to purchase books!)
2. More traffic to the site.

---

Ok, first off, I have zero affiliation with Logos Bible Software, beyond the fact that I love it when I am doing my sermon prep.

That said, I'd like to write Bob Pritchett and propose two things.

1. I'd like to send him a script I wrote that mines C.SE and Biblical Hermeneutics for all scripture references, and puts them in a database, so that a user of Logos could see relevant Questions asked by people about certain bible refs. As a pastor, I'd find that really useful, because it helps me know what people find interesting / confusing / useful on given topics. It's a win for Logos, because it's yet another reference, and an interactive one at that. Logos could advertise it as "ask about things". It's a win for C.SE, because the links would drive more traffic to our site.
2. I'd also propose that Logos might give out book credits as prizes for contests on our site. I've seen other sites have "Question weeks" where questions and answers on a given topic are placed in a lottery, and a randomly selected poster wins the prize. If we could convince them to sponsor a contest or two each month, where the winner gets, say $10-$15 worth of book credits, it'd be another win-win. We'd get free books to boost our libraries (and oddly enough, I think we're geeky enough to go for that), and Logos at least gets to put their name out there to the demographic they want want most - geeks interested in theology. And, again, it would drive traffic to our site, because I know they'll promote the fact that you can win credits over here.

A few things I like about the company, btw, you can actually do a little bit with the free products, and even with $10-$15 in credit, you could get a book or two that's useful. Plus, as a book publishing company, I think they share our values of "just get as much info out here as you can."

So, before I write this, I guess I need a clarification from the community. Are these things in keeping with the terms of service of this site?  I know we don't promote products in posts (and that wouldn't change), but I do think there're some win wins if it's possible.

Ideally, if there is someone from the StackExchange HQ who could chime in, I'd really like to know if this is doable.

Note again: I do not work for Logos, and I have not talked to them. (And I'm purposely not linking, bc I don't want to be thought of as advertising). What I want to know is if
A. This is in any way doable
B. If anybody thinks it's a good idea.

Comment: "Live" sites usually have a call for non-profit/[open source advertising](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects/) I'd say this is a pretty good idea. I'd imagine if you used the [API](http://api.stackexchange.com) you'd get even more traction, that way you could advertise your own plugin for logos (which in turn would advertise, this site, Logos and your own mad skillz (not that we should boast)).

Comment: @WaxEagle I'd like to add the featured tag to this question to see if we can get more responses / activity.  It sounds like from discussion that if there is more community support, they could may see about doing this.

Comment: Right now, we've only had 9 votes: 7 up and 2 down, which says to me that overall this has support, but it isn't unanimous. I'd love to get some discussion going around this, and see if the objections could be handled.